# How do I print the windows content which is at the top and not at the background

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search criteria which displays some results.

In the results when I click a hyperlink (it is an aspx application ) it opened  a javascript window  with some content in it.

And it automatically pop-ups up a Print Dialog asking for print.

When I click on print it is printing the background content and as well as the window content.

But if I explicitly right click and select print on the  new JavaScript window  it is printing fine.

The ASPX application is not the one which we control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with a special style sheet that targets [media type](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) of print.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="print.css" media="print">

body{
  background:none;
  /*Other css rules for the popped window*/
}
#someElement{ /* do not print this element*/
  display:none;
}
```

Another good resource is from [A List Apart - CSS Design: Going to Print](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/).

Comment: Usually they will not print, however without more context to the question it is hard to definitively say what is going on. The use of a separate style sheet should help get the op a start in the right direction.

Comment: Oh I agree with you, your answer is good. That's was just a suggestion for your `background:none`. I would rather add a `#background { display:none }` (according to what the user is trying to do ^^)

Comment: @LekisS, ahhh gotcha, good point, adjusted a bit to show that intent.